# Remotely run "rosrun rviz rviz" from launch file

Tags: ros, rviz, roslaunch, remote, rosrun

[image: Rosanswers logo]

All,

Is there a way I can launch a launch file on the master that runs rviz on my workstation?

If so, could you provide an example?

Thank you!
Andy

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/53821/remotely-run-%22rosrun-rviz-rviz%22-from-launch-file/) by [Andrius](https://answers.ros.org/users/3812/andrius/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2013-01-31

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [georgebrindeiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/2573/georgebrindeiro/) on 2013-01-31**:
Could you clarify your question? From what I understood, you have two machines. Master is running on a machine that is not your workstation (a robot?). You want to be able to automatically run rviz on your workstation when you execute a launch file on the other machine. Is that right?

**Comment by [Andrius](https://answers.ros.org/users/3812/andrius/) on 2013-01-31**:
That is correct. Any thoughts on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should be able to do that with the [`<machine>` tag](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roslaunch/XML/machine).

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-01-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Andrius](https://answers.ros.org/users/3812/andrius/) on 2013-01-31**:
could you expound on that a bit? the machine tag seemed like a logical place to start, but i'm not sure of the syntax to remotely run rviz from my master to my workstation

**Comment by [georgebrindeiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/2573/georgebrindeiro/) on 2013-02-01**:
Examples can be found here: http://www.ros.org/wiki/roslaunch/XML/machine#Examples
Are there any tags you can't figure out?